# In case of text analysis, when I apply fit() method, what exactly happens? And what does transform() do on the text data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, sentiment-analysis

In case of text analysis, when I apply fit() method, what exactly happens? And what does transform() do on the data?

I can understand it for numerical data type but unable to visualize it for text data.

I have a text array

```
sents_processed[0:5]
['so there is no way for me plug in here in us unless go by converter',
 'good case excellent value',
 'great for jawbone',
 'tied charger for conversations lasting more than minutes major problems',
 'mic is great']
```

Now to vectorize it, I use CountVectorizer class:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer= 'word', tokenizer= None, preprocessor= None, stop_words= None, max_features= 4500)
data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(sents_processed)
print(data_features.toarray())
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

I know that I will get vectors of 4500 length. However, I am unable to visualize what exactly fit method would have done behind the scene and how exactly data would have been then transformed by tranform function? Specially that given data is text type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a simple exmaple:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
text = ['this is a sentence', 'this is another sentence', 'not a sentence']
```

Here i've three sentences

```
vector = CountVectorizer(analyzer= 'word', tokenizer= None, max_features= 4500)
dt = vector.fit_transform(text)
```

The first step in this process is creation of a vocabulary. It assigns a number to every word come in all of the sentences

```
print(vector.vocabulary_) = {'this': 4, 'is': 1, 'sentence': 3, 'another': 0, 'not': 2}
```

Now it deals with the corresponding index of words instead of word itself.
Now method <vector.fit_transform()> convert these sentences into numbers based on the index provided in the vocabulary

```
data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
print(data_features.toarray())
= [[0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0]]
```

if you just analyse the array it just shows the sentences. In vocabulary of five words to represent a sentence in array form, first we have a array of five(size of vocabulary) zeroes representing a empty sentence

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0].
```

now if we pick up our first sentence and put 1 in the above array at the index corresponding to that we get that array

```
[0            1(is)       0          1(sentence)           1(this)]
[1(another)   1(is)       0          1(sentence)           1(this)]
[0            0           1(not)     1(sentence)           0      ]
```

if the word comes in that sentence it is 1 else 0

you just take a closer look and get the idea how it is coming or you can read about word Embedding.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation is very clear. So if a sentence have a word repeated multiple times. How that word is represented in array form? e.g. Lets suppose **"Another word has another meaning and differ from sentence to sentence"** is one of the sentence. You can see "another" and "sentence" are appearing twice. What would happen here?

Comment: in that case index corresponding to word 'another' and 'sentence' will have 2 instead of one. If repeated three times than 3. Don't forget to upvote if you like it

Comment: Thank you so much. I asked this question because I read that when we have numerical data, fit() funtion calculates mean and std and tranform() function substitute these values for the data. However, I was not able to understand same for text type data.